# PHP get variable from form select on live

Tags: php, forms, variables, live

i need to get variable from select option in form on live, because it is used in next field in the same form. Any clue how to do it ? I guess it can be done with javascript but i have no idea how to use javascript. Thanks in advance.
Here's the code of form :

```
  echo '  <form action="dodaj_harmonogram.php" method="post">';

echo ' <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Nazwa harmonogramu:</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="nazwa_harmonogramu" required />
      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
  </div>';
 echo 'Profil:<br /> 
                            <select name="profil">
                              '; pobierz_profile(); 
                              echo'</select><br>';
 echo 'Playlista:<br /> 
 <select name="playlista" id="lista">
 '; pobierz_playlisty($id_playlisty); 
echo'</select><br>';
$czas_playlisty = zaokraglanieczasu(pobierz_czas_utworow_playlisty($id_playlisty));
$czas_sekundy = ceil($czas_playlisty);
echo ' <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Odstęp (min):</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="number" min="'.$czas_sekundy.'" name="odstep" required />
      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
  </div>';
echo ' <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Data od</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="date" name="data_od" required />
      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
  </div>';
echo ' <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Data do</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="date" name="data_do" required />
      <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
  </div>';
echo ' Dni:<br />' ;

?>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 20%;">
<thead><th>Nd</th><th>Pn</th><th>Wt</th><th>Śr</th><th>Cz</th><th>Pt</th><th>Sb</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="nd" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pn" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="wt" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="sr" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="cz" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="pt" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="sb" value='1'></td> 
</tbody>  
</table>
<br>  
<br>   
Godziny:<br />  
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead><th>0</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th><th>8</th><th>9</th><th>10</th><th>11</th>
<th>12</th><th>13</th><th>14</th><th>15</th><th>16</th><th>17</th><th>18</th><th>19</th><th>20</th><th>21</th><th>22</th><th>23</th>
</thead> 
<tbody>                 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="0" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="1" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="2" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="3" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="4" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="5" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="6" value='1'></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="7" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="8" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="9" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="10" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="11" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="12" value='1'></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="13" value='1'></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="14" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="15" value='1'></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="16" value='1'></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="17" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="18" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="19" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="20" value='1'></td> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="21" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="22" value='1'></td>  
<td><input type="checkbox" name="23" value='1'></td> 
</tbody> 
</table>    
 <br>  
<br>   

    <script>$(function(){
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click", function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'rgb(36, 255, 0)');
        else
            $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'rgba(202, 202, 202, 0)');
    });
});</script>


   <input type="submit" value="Dodaj "button" class="btn btn-info"></button>
 </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'on live'? Do you mean when the value of the select changes? Edit: Also do you need to put the value of the select box somewhere or just store it in a variable?

Comment: I mean that, when i select an option from that select, value of this option goes to a variable, because it is used in next field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include jQuery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Then use an event handler to check when the select changes 
$('select').on('change', function()
{
  // Show an alert
  alert( "The new value of the select is " + $(this).val() );
  // You should place your logic here to do what you want with that value 
  // E.g. change the page 
  document.location.href = $(this).val();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to get this selection value to a variable e.g $example. I don't need any alert. I need this variable to be extracted from <select name="playlista" id="lista">

Comment: It cannot be a PHP variable `$example` this is javascript, it is client side (runs in the browser), PHP runs on the server. `$(this).val()` will contain the `<option>` value of what ever was selected from the `<select>`

Comment: so can i use $(this).val() instad of $id_playlisty in $czas_playlisty = zaokraglanieczasu(pobierz_czas_utworow_playlisty($id_playlisty));
$czas_sekundy = ceil($czas_playlisty); ???

Comment: Calm down. You have to understand the difference between client and server. You know that the php code only runs once and therefore cannot be used for 'live' interactions. If you want to do live interaction you use javascript like Jake's answer described - if you must use this variable in a php page you can send it via a POST request.

Comment: And when i include Your code (script src and script) and when i change the selection, nothing happens, no alert pops out etc

Comment: Ok, i can see the difference between server and client, but this selection before submiting the form is client side am i right? So the selection could be used in next field in form i guess.

Comment: @user3205780 ok so do you submit the form with the select button before the next form? If that's the case then in dodaj_harmonogram.php you can use $_POST['profil'] to access the value of the select.

Comment: The javascript occurs only in the browser, it won't `talk` to PHP (well not without AJAX). So javascript can affect things within the current page, like going to a new page or show/hiding a `div` when a select is changed.

Comment: Nope, i am submiting whole form, not each field. (after submiting this form there is a insert into postgresql db)

Comment: Ok, i guess that best option would be to make this form two stage. But thanks for info :)